# Dojo CheckMulti Select - how to move check box to the right of label

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using a dojo checked multiselect in a page i'm developing. I'm quite new to Dojo so found and example which i used 
http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/894af/ 
this fitted my needs (well almost). I want to position the check box on the right have side of the check box options.

I've tried manipulating the dom by overriding the postCreate method on the widget but to no avail. 
Has anyone any suggestions on how i might achieve this?

this is what i tried

```
var MyCheckedMultiSelect = declare(CheckedMultiSelect, {


    postCreate: function() {   
        this.inherited(arguments);
        var tableRow = dom.byId("dojox_form__CheckedMultiSelectMenuItem_1");
        var firstTableCell = query(".dijitMenuItemIconCell", tableRow);         
        domConstruct.place(firstTableCell, tableRow, "last");
    }



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change style is enough, see [my change of jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seanzhao/894af/568/)

the style change as:

```
td.dijitMenuItemLabel{
    float:left;
}


td.dijitMenuItemIconCell {
    float:right;
    width: 16px;
    height:16px;

tr.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectMenuItemChecked td.dijitMenuItemIconCell {
    float:right;
```

Comment: If this is the answer, you can approve it,